# Running java file in command line when not in same directory but without typing full directory

Tags: java, mips, mars-simulator

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
java -jar Mars4_5.java file_name.asm
```

If Mars4_5.java isn't in the same directory as file_name.asm?

I've stored the file in my C: drive's main folder, so I can run this:

```
java -jar C:/Mars4_5.java file_name.asm
```

However, I haven't found a way to make it just Mars4_5.java, as I could do if it were in the same directory.

With Python, it's quite easy to store it in system path and call Python in the terminal.

Comment: `java -jar Mars4_5.java`? Are you sure you didn't mean `Mars4_5.jar`? Personally I'd write a shell script to run this an put that somewhere on the executable path.

Comment: You can run cd c:\ as a separate command then run `java -jar Mars4_5.java file_name.asm`

Comment: Probably not a good idea to put files directly into C:. I don't really see what the problem is. You could even edit a shortcut icon to have the full path to each file and Java would run it with a double click

Comment: @g00se Hmm, is there a reason why it's bad to have files directly in C:? Would it harm me in the long run and should I move it out of there asap?

Comment: Directories directly off the root are really for the system. In fact they are not even writable by a normal user normally. Things like this are better placed under the user's home tree. For one thing, they will be backed up easily from there